# Syntax issue with Qlikview STORE INTO qvd

Tags: qlikview

I'm consistently unable to store data into a QVD file. The syntax I've been using works perfectly in other applications, but for some reason I can't get it to work in the application I'm trying to finish.

I've successfully developed a data model, now need to loop through by years, reduce the data for just the specific years, and then save that out to individual QVD files.

Here's the code:

```
FOR i = $(vL.MinFY) TO $(vL.MaxFY)
  LET _table = 'T_FACT_$(i)_GL_BALANCES';

  [$(_table)]:
  LOAD
    *
  RESIDENT [FINAL BALANCES]
  WHERE LEFT([Year-Period],4) = $(i) 
  ;

  IF NoOfRows('$(_table)') > 0 THEN
    STORE $(_table) INTO [$(vG.TransformQVDPath)$(_table).QVD];
  END IF 

  LET vRowCount_$(i) = NoOfRows('$(_table)');
  DROP TABLE [$(_table)];
NEXT
```

The script burps on the `DROP TABLE` statement, and nothing is saved to QVD. I've tried various combinations of dollar-sign expansion, with and without quotes, brackets, etc.

Hope someone can help me determine what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

DOH! Figured it out.

The `LOAD` statement requires a `NOCONCATENATE`, or else each iteration of the table is simply concatenated with the source table.  Updated script for the load section is:

```
  [$(_table)]:
  NOCONCATENATE LOAD
    *
  RESIDENT [FINAL BALANCES]
  WHERE LEFT([Year-Period],4) = $(i) 
  ;
```

After doing that everything worked as expected.